# How do I stop the "Found new hardware wizard" appearing?

Tags: windows, hardware, drivers

As part of our product we use 3rd party hardware and drivers.  Unfortunately, these drivers aren't signed so up pops the "Found new hardware wizard" when installing or upgrading our product.  Our product is web based and allows the users access to everything they need remotely, apart from this one case.

Is there a registry hack or other OS setting that will stop the wizard appearing?

Can we sign the drivers ourselves?

Could we write a program that would click "Next, Next, Next" on the wizard that will work on all language variants of Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is 2 ways to get silent installation:
1) [Sign the driver](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/winlogo/default.mspx) and that can be hard/impossible if you don't have the driver source code.
2) You can write a [co-installer dll](http://www.osronline.com/ddkx/install/coinst_5p0n.htm) using [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms791137.aspx) api's. The problem that this is not reliable and from our experience there is a lot of workarounds for different Windows flavors.

The only 100% reliable option will be option one.